# How to include related Entities using dynamic queries

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2, dynamic-queries

I am taking the values from a search form in my application to build a dynamic query:

```
string queryString = @"SELECT VALUE USERS FROM ProjectDBEntities.Users AS Users 
WHERE ";
```

There are two tables in the database, **Users** and **Photo**, table Photo has a column **UserId** that links to the Users table. A one to many relationship exists between Users and Photo.

After some iteration through the form values and adding System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter values, I end up with following query:

```
SELECT VALUE USERS FROM ProjectDBEntities.Users AS Users 
WHERE Users.CountryId = 2
```

Then I have this code:

```
System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<Users> usersQuery =
                new System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<Users>(queryString, _db);
```

The usersQuery  object does not contain the Image data for each Users. In my View I can iterate through the Users.Image but the Image count is always zero. Do I have to include or attach the Image data somewhere? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an `.Include()` for the image property:

```
System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<Users> usersQuery =
            new System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<Users>(queryString, _db).Include("Image");
```